# Using nested map with filter in React JSX results in Cannot read properties of undefined error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a nested map inside a React JSX component that is resulting in an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'state').
```

I believe it is referring to the internal map.

The code is as follows:

```
<Col xs="12" sm="12" md="12" lg="12">
    <Row>
        {this.state.watchdog ?
            this.state.uniqueClients.map(function (item, i) {
                return (
                    <li key={i}>{item}

                        {this.state.watchdog.filter(client => client.includes(item)).map(filteredClient => (
                            <React.Fragment>

                                <DataGrid id="grid-container"
                                    dataSource={filteredClient}
                                    keyExpr="ID"
                                    showBorders={true}
                                >
                                    <Column dataField="Prefix" width={70} caption="Title" />
                                    <Column dataField="FirstName" />
                                    <Column dataField="LastName" />
                                    <Column dataField="Position" width={170} />
                                    <Column dataField="State" width={125} />
                                    <Column dataField="BirthDate" dataType="date" />
                                    <MasterDetail
                                        enabled={true}
                                        component={DetailTemplate}
                                    />
                                </DataGrid>
                            </React.Fragment>

                        ))}
                    </li>
                )
            })

            : null}
    </Row>
</Col>
```

First I check that the this.state.watchdog is populated. If so I then write out the heading of the client (there are multiple clients so I am creating a DataGrid per client). The task is to create a DataGrid for the given client. However I get the error even though I know that the state data exists as I checked for valid data first.

Below is an example of the lit of objects in watchdog state:

```
[
{site: 'site1', client: 'client1'},
{site: 'site2', client: 'client1'},
{site: 'site3', client: 'client1'},
{site: 'site1', client: 'client2'},
{site: 'site2', client: 'client2'}
]
```

The idea is to get the second mapping was to filter the watchdog state data according to the client name, but I can't get the second map to work at all.

Thanks

Comment: `(item, i) => ` instead of `function (item, i)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after many different searches and variations this is the code that worked:

```js
<Col xs="12" sm="12" md="12" lg="12">
  <Row>
    {this.state.watchdog
      ? this.state.uniqueClients
        ? this.state.uniqueClients.map((myitem, is) => {
            return (
              <React.Fragment>
                <li key={is}>{myitem}</li>
                {this.state.watchdog
                  .filter((individual) => {
                    return individual.client == myitem;
                  })
                  .map((filteredClient) => (
                    <React.Fragment>
                      <DataGrid
                        id="grid-container"
                        dataSource={filteredClient}
                        keyExpr="ID"
                        showBorders={true}
                      >
                        <Column dataField="client" width={70} caption="Title" />
                        <Column dataField="client" />
                        <Column dataField="site" />
                        <MasterDetail
                          enabled={true}
                          component={DetailTemplate}
                        />
                      </DataGrid>
                    </React.Fragment>
                  ))}
              </React.Fragment>
            );
          })
        : null
      : null}
  </Row>
</Col>
```

The change was:

```js
this.state.uniqueClients.map((item, i) => {
```

from

```js
this.state.uniqueClients.map(function (item, i) {
```

I have no clue as to the reasoning.